# Problems recovering data from a 3.5" HD with a HD enclosure

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-explorer, external-hard-drive, enclosures

I have an All in One HP TouchSmart computer that has gone completely crazy since I installed Windows 7 updates. I can't reach the login screen for Windows. So I removed the hard drive and plugged in a SATA HD Enclosure to access it with another computer to recover my files.

Once I opened the drive on my computer, I can see all the files that were on the HD. If I go into My Pictures, and click on a picture, I can open up the picture in Windows Preview.

After that, I select all the files on the HD and copy them over to my laptop (plenty of space). While it begins by counting all the files that need to be transferred, I get an error saying a particular document is unreadable (PNG file). I click Try Again to no avail. So I end clicking cancel.

If I revisit my HD with Windows Explorer, all the images (JPEG, PNG etc) have an icon for Windows Preview instead of a thumbnail of the picture and if I open one up, it says "Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because either the picture is deleted, or it's in a location that isn't available."

If anyone can explain to me this bizarre phenomenon, it would be much appreciated. If you can also think of a solution for me to retrieve these I would be very grateful.

Comment if you need more information,

Comment: There could be problems reading the sectors where some files are located.  I would suggest cloning the drive, then trying to copy files off of it if at all possible.  Of course this is more involved but may be the best solution.

Comment: How would you recommend I clone the drive?

Comment: Typically if the health of the drive is in question I will use a bit for bit copy, something like `dd_rescue`.

Comment: So I tried doing a dd_rescue and a simple dd but I kept getting "Input/output error" and "0 in, 0 out, 0 bytes transferred". What would you recommend. I think the drive is fine, because when I disconnect it and reconnect it works again for a few minutes then makes files unreadable again. Thanks for your help @jmreicha.

Comment: Just to be sure, `dd` is NOT the same as `dd_rescue`.  As an additional step if you haven't already, remove the HDD from the enclosure and hook it directly up to the computer, USB does not handle I/O errors gracefully.  Finally, I would also advise to be very careful when attempting a clone, just be sure to double check your work.

Comment: I try both running it through my enclosure and directly on the computer (Ubuntu Live USB Drive). Still the same error. Do you think it could have something to do with permissions? Thanks gain @jmreicha

Comment: if you're running from a live cd did you `su` before you ran it?

Comment: I used sudo yes.

Comment: Can't remember on Ubuntu but I think you might actually have to run the command as root, so `sudo su` then the command.  Alternatively I know you can do it from a Knoppix live cd without having to worry about permissions, etc.